# Expression does not evaluate to a column or table name error when updating object in MapBasic

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, update

I tries to set styles for all objects in my `processing_table`, but gets `Expression does not evaluate to a column or table name`

My code:

```vb
'...
pen_style = currentpen() 'get_pen(styles_table_name, obj_type, class_id, selected_scale)
altering_obj = processing_table.obj
alter object altering_obj
    info OBJ_INFO_PEN, pen_style
cmd = "select * from processing_table where objectid = " & id_value & " and class_id = " & class_id & " into one_obj"
run command cmd
update one_obj set obj = altering_obj where rowid = 1 ' Expression does not evaluate to a column or table name error
close table one_obj
'...
```

And sandbox script works perfectly:

```vb
'...
query = "select * from " & selected_layer_name & " where " & id_field_name  & " = " & filter_value & "into filtered"
run command query
id_field = "filtered.objectid"
while not eot(filtered)
    id_value = id_field
    altering_obj = filtered.obj
    alter object altering_obj
        info OBJ_INFO_SYMBOL, point_symbol

    query = "select * from " & selected_layer_name & " where objectid = " & id_value & " into one_obj"
    run command query

    update one_obj set obj = altering_obj where rowid = 1
    close table one_obj
    fetch next from filtered
wend
close table filtered
'...
```

I can't understand where these scripts are different. Algorithm is same:

1. Alter object from processing table
2. Select this object into `one_obj` table
3. Update it

Both scripts I checked with same tables.
May be reason is in different connection to tables?

In sandbox I use already opened table:

```vb
selected_layer_name = layerinfo(window_id, suitable_layers(selected_layer), LAYER_INFO_NAME)
query = "select * from " & selected_layer_name & " where " & id_field_name  & " = " & filter_value & "into filtered"
```

And in non-working script I opens table from disk:

```vb
cmd = "open table " & chr$(34) & tab_file & chr$(34)
run command cmd
table_name = TableInfo(0, TAB_INFO_NAME)
'...
cmd = "select * from " & table_name & " into processing_table"
run command cmd
```

Comment: set a table name (in your case "processing_table") as a variable (string) and try

Comment: On what line is the compiler throwing the error? Also, you might want to use a Print command to inspect your `cmd` variable each time you build a command string (e.g. `Print cmd`) to make sure that they are being created as you expect. Once you're happy that the command strings are fine then you can comment out or delete those print commands.

Comment: I also get curious when I see people fetching data from a table, changing it and then doing a select before they update the same table again. In your case you get the spatial object from one record, you change it and then you do a select to - probably - select the same record again. You can update the record by referring to the record you just read from using the ROWID

Comment: Yes, may be I wrote monkey code :)
I did it by gathering code samples from Google.
Sorry, but I'm beginner in MapBasic and also dislike whole Basic languages family.

Comment: OK, sorry did mean to offend you. Generally speaking you can in most cases do your update via the Update statement and by using a custom function. This will be a lot better to understand when looking at the code afterwards and it will also create faster running code. Let me try and find and example

Comment: Have a look at the ChangeColor function in this thread: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153164/how-can-i-change-region-style-in-mapbasic

Comment: Thank for advices! I hope that I will can take time for try it, but now I already have working script and need to continue my work. And I didn't take offense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error reason was not in above code samples but in code that performs earlier:

```vb
query = "select obj from " & selected_layer_name & " where str$(object) = " & chr$(34) & str & chr$(34) & " and class_id = " & class_id & " into temp_obj"
run command query
```

When I changes `select obj ...` to `select * ...` updating became work.

But I still not understood why error happens.

Comment: Obj is a special field used for accessing the spatial object, it doesn't always work the same as a normal attribute field. I'm pretty sure you can not select just the obj column as you've tried to do. You CAN select a valid attribute column and then refer to the object from the results.

Comment: It's very strange for me. Then why this query worked?
After query executing I got access to `obj` and worked with it.
And bug appeared in futher code.

Comment: Oh, maybe what happened is that by only selecting the special `obj` field you excluded the other special field `RowID`. So, when you tried to do the update using `RowID` it failed to find that column. Speculation as I don't know exactly how it works as I've never only selected `obj` on it's own from a table.

Comment: No, `RowID` is not a reason. I tried update table without filtering by row id (in my code updating table has one row, I checked it in browser window) - result was same.