# One liner to change table style in mapbasic

Tags: symbology, mapbasic

Is there a one liner using Set Style to change all the symbology of one tab file?

I want it to be 
`Global Pen (1,2,0)   Global Brush (1,16777215,16777215)`

There's https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mapinfo-l/BZM5ZXfdXSY and http://www.mapbasichelp.com/2014/05/change-object-style-with-mapbasic-alter.html but these seem more complex than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the style on objects in a table in MapInfo Pro is "complex" because you need to set the style directly on the spatial object. You can't just update a column.

This also mean that you need to modify the object and then write this back to the record in the table.

To make it easier and to improve the performance, it's recommended to do this via a function.

Have a look at this answer: [How can I change region style in MapBasic](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153164/how-can-i-change-region-style-in-mapbasic/153180#153180)

It's the Function ChangeColor that you can use to alter the style. There is also an example on how to use the function in an Update statement.